# React и умное изменение стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, state

Друзья, добрый день.

Есть стейт:

```html
  const [ingridients,setIngridients] = useState({
        bacon:0,
        pepper:0
    })
```

И есть функция, которая *должна* менять любой из элементов объекта, но пока меняет только pepper:

```html
function plus(ingridient){
    setIngridients({...ingridients,pepper:ingridients.pepper+1})
}
```

Функция берет старое значение стейта и увеличивает в нем значение на pepper+1

На текущий момент в аргумент ingridient приходит название того свойства, которое я хочу менять, чтобы то можно было подставить в деструктуризацию для изменения. Если коротко, представляю себе эту конструкцию так:

```html
function plus(ingridient){ //Тут в функцию приходит название ингридиента, допустим - bacon

    setIngridients({...ingridients,ingridient:ingridients.ingridient+1}) 
    // А тут мы подставляем то что получили, но это не работает
}
```

Позволяет ли текущая конструкция вообще подставлять в него значения?

Comment: И потом увеличивать значения ингридиентов следующим образом:

<button onClick={()=>plus('pepper')}>plus</button>
<button onClick={()=>plus('meat')}>plus</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function plus(ingridient) {
  setIngridients((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [ingridient]: prevState[ingridient] + 1
  }))
}
```

Comment: Cердечно благодарю вас!

Comment: Вот еще одна из возможных реализаций: setIngridients({...ingridients,[ingridient]:ingridients[ingridient] +1})